# How to generate Changelog based on bitbucket commits using fastlane

Tags: bitbucket, fastlane, changelog

I would like to automate Changelog genereation based on bitbucket commits using fastlane.
fastlane is providing a *changelog_from_git_commits* which takes all the commits texts with an option to exclude merges.

How would it be possible to generate changlog based on some smart commits using only defined keywords, e.g fix:, feat: etc

Thanks